# Worked days count

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I have a monthly report on google sheets(excel format) that I am trying to to fix. So I have 17 workers. The formula that Iam trying to make is, it should count how many days workers worked in a month. Workers day-offs are not obvious(we decided everyday) it shows in the graph, name, job location or day-off [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGSAO.jpg)
it is in P column and i tried to write this formula:

```
=If(And("P2,P21,P43,P65,P86,P103,P123,P144,P165,P186,P207,P228,P249,P270,P291,P312,P333,P354,P375,P396,P417,P438,P459,P481,P502,P523,P545,P566,P588,P609,P630","x=1","x=off=0"))
```

I know this is not correct, does anyone know how to put it together? this formula is only for one worker, for others I will copy paste

Answer (score 0):

The function you're looking for is networkedays
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092979?hl=en

Please note that if you're using Google spreadsheets you should tag your question appropriately (there are some similarities but it's not identical)

Comment: I saw this, can I add "If" function? Because the dayoffs are not exact, it might change

Comment: It seems like you should be able to, or alternatively define a range for the days off